# How to download all TikTok videos of a particular user

Tags: download, wget, youtube-dl

How can I download all videos of a particular user, from Tiktok web (not Android)? I access TikTok using Ubuntu desktop, through browser. I know that it is easy to download each video separately.

I am looking for a browser extension or a small program (like youtube-dl), or a web service, where I can download all the videos, with the caption as the file name, in a single click.

Youtube-dl does not work. It gives "ERROR: Unsupported URL".

Any technique (wget, httrack, python script, bash script) which can do this will do. Can anyone suggest some solution?

Comment: @Ivanov Thanks for the response. In youtube-dl, there are 3 [open issues](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+tiktok) with similar requests. It seems that no one has developed a solution to this problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the chrome extension [myfaveTT](https://myfavett.com/). It can download all videos from people you follow on tiktok. So, you can download one particular user if that user is in your following list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Once I am outside India, I shall check this. I am not in a position to check this chrome extension now, since Indian central government banned usage of TikTok. Still upvoting.